# таймер анимаций

Tags: lua

timer.Create("asfasffa",1,0,function () 
RunConsoleCommand("_darkrp_doanimation" 1642) 
end)

выдает ошибку

RunConsoleCommand: Command has invalid characters! (_darkrp_doanimation 1642 (' ')) 
The first parameter of this function should contain only the command, the second parameter should contain arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка заключается в некорректном использовании функции `RunConsoleCommand`, которая должна содержать 2 параметра: *команду* и *аргумент*.

У Вас отсутствует запятая между командой и аргументом, о чём компилятор вам и сообщает принимая всё в скобках за *команду*, но не видя *аргумента*.

Для решения проблемы исправте Ваш код на:

timer.Create("asfasffa",1,0,function () RunConsoleCommand("_darkrp_doanimation", "1642") end)